# How to preserve uninterpolatable sections of a string with $interpolate in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Currently I run interpolation on a string like the following.

```
var originalStr = 'Hello_{{world}}_{{nonExistingVariable}}';
var interpolatedStr = $interpolate(originalStr)({ world: 'world' });
```

The result of the above would be `'Hello_World_'`. I would like to preserve the value of the sections that can't be interpolated in order to perform a manual replace in the future. E.g interpolatedStr should be `Hello_World_{{nonExistingVariable}}`

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not save the original string and run the interpolation again when you get new data? That's how the AngularJS framework does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backslash to prevent interpolation specifically if you want:

> $interpolate provides a mechanism for escaping interpolation markers. Start and end markers can be escaped by preceding each of their characters with a REVERSE SOLIDUS U+005C (backslash). It will be rendered as a regular start/end marker, and will not be interpreted as an expression or binding.

See [AngularJS $interpolate Service API Reference - escaped interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate#escaped-interpolation)

```
'Hello_{{world}}_\{\{nonExistingVariable\}\}' 
->
Hello_World_{{nonExistingVariable}}
```